# How to Identfy encoding in openldap?

Tags: ubuntu, encoding, utf-8, ldap

I have  slapd 2.4.25-1.1ubuntu4.1 installed on a server in Ubuntu 10. I guess by default it is UTF-8. How could i confirm what encoding is used in the open ldap server? Can we actually change encoding?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that depends on the attribute Syntax you are asking about.
[For strings, RFC: 2253 says](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2253.txt):

"   Otherwise, if the AttributeValue is of a type which has a string
   representation, the value is converted first to a UTF-8 string
   according to its syntax specification (see for example section 6 of
   [4]).
"